# Reinforcement learning with hard constraints

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, monte-carlo-tree-search

The environment is a directed graph that consists of **nodes which have their own "goodness"**(marked green) and **edges that have prices**(marked red). In this environment exists **Price(P)** constraint. The goal is to accumulate **the most "goodness" points from nodes**, as possible while making a circle(for example 0-->6-->5-->0) and **not exceeding price constraint.**.

I managed to implement Q-Learning algorithm when there are no constraints, but I don't fully understand how to add Hard Constrains, while approximating Q-Function.

For instance, starting point is 0. Price limit is 13. Taking path 0-->1-->2-->3-->4-->5-->0 wouldn't be a valid choice for **Agent**, because at node 5 **price**(13) limit was reached, therefore, **Agent** should be **punished for violating constraints**. However, taking path 0-->6-->5-->0 would be a correct choice for the **Agent** and therefore, he should be **rewarded**. What I do not understand, how to tell *Agent* that sometimes going from 5 to 0 is perfect choice and sometimes it is not applicable, because some constraints where violated. I tried to give huge penalty if price constraint was violated and ended episode immediately, but that didn't seem to workout.

**My question(s):**

- How to add hard constraints to RL algorithms like Q-Learning?
- Is Q-Learning a valid choice for that kind of problem?
- Should other algorithms be chosen like Monte Carlo Tree Search
  instead of Q-Learning.

I assume it is a very common problem in real world scenarios, but I couldn't find any examples about that.

[image]

Comment: Is this an episodic game as in the agent fails if it overspends and then resets at the beginning. And also the agent resets position when it does the correct 0-6-5-0 trajectory or does it just keep going? What does your current observation space and reward function look like for the working game?